# Getting recurly token with incomplete information

Tags: recurly

To get a recurly token, you must submit an object with credit card and billing address data. What if the user would like to use the same credit card that is stored in recurly, but change his/her billing address? How can you use the recurly.token function to receive a token without sending the credit card information?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming PHP.

I suggest storing the recurly_id that is returned after creating an account together with your user's login-information.

By doing that, you can later use

```
$billing_info = Recurly_BillingInfo::get($recurly_id);
```

to get the billing object.

On that object, you can change info through the overloaded properties (address1, city, country, full list can be found on Source page). So, together with a simple html form you could create an 'Update Billing Info' page on your site to allow users to update their info.

After changing what you want, don't forget to call:

```
$billing_info->update();
```

Source: https://docs.recurly.com/api/billing-info#update-billing-info-token